How to read and verify digital signature for EXE and DLL in java
I want to validate the EXEs and DLLs before invoking in java. I searched on internet, but i didnt find any proper solution.
My requirement is, to validate any signed EXE or DLL by extracting a digital certificate and verifying it.
I don't like using signtool, by invoking with Runtime. I want a solution with Java or third-party libraries.
thanks in advance.
I have tried AI tools (Chat GPT/Bard), the expected result is not available.
since invoking signtool and cmd will be heavy. I want with Java library or plain Java.

That is an OS (Windows) specific feature, it is very unlikely that there is a pure Java implementation that can do that. This probably needs a native solution (like a DLL) that can be invoked from Java using JNI. In any case recommendations of libraries and other off site resources are off-topic for Stackoverflow.

The closest solution is Jsign (disclaimer: I'm the author), that's a pure Java code signing tool that also provides an API to extract the signatures from EXE/DLL files. The syntax looks like this:
Signable signable = Signable.of(file);
List<CMSSignedData> signatures = signable.getSignatures();

It doesn't performs the verification yet, but you can easily implement the verification of the extracted CMS signature with Bouncy Castle.

Thanks a lot for the reply. I'm new to verifying the digital signatures of Exe and DLL. I want to know the rest of the implementation.  also please share with me if there are articles about verifying signatures in java and  Bouncy Castle.
